# Reactive function shiny+ggplot2 in shiny error

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am trying to create R Shiny app which can take in a dataset, choose from the input value, which item is to be plotted. I am facing issues when I am trying to filter the dataset based on the input value in the reactive function. I also get errors in ggplot function. I get "object of type 'closure' is not subsettable" and "ggplot doesnot know how to deal with a reactive function". I tried tmpdf with () and even without. Nothing seems to work.

Server.R

```
    require(dplyr)
    require(ggplot2)

    shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    #This function is repsonsible for loading in the selected file
      filedata <- reactive({
      infile <- input$datafile
      if (is.null(infile)) {
      # User has not uploaded a file yet
      return(NULL)
      }
      read.csv(infile$datapath)
      })

   #This function is repsonsible for loading the AS Item nos in the selected file
    output$asitmno <- renderUI({
    df <-filedata()
    if (is.null(df)) return(NULL)
    itmchoices <- unique(df$ASItemNo)
    selectInput("asitmno", "AS Item No:", choices = itmchoices)
      })

  #This function is triggered when the action button is pressed
    getplot <- reactive({
    if (input$getplot == 0) return(NULL)
    df=filedata()
    itm=input$asitmno
    if (is.null(df)) return(NULL)

  #This function filters the dataset for the given item    
    tmpdf <- reactive({
    if (is.null(df)) return(NULL)
    df$MonthDate<-as.Date(df$MonthDate, "%m/%d/%Y")
    df<-df[input$ASItemNo %in% input$asitmno]
    })


  #This function plots the prices for the selected item
    output$plot <- renderPlot({

    p<-ggplot(tmpdf(), aes(y = stdcom, x = MonthDate, color = "Commodity Price")) + geom_line() +geom_line(data = tmpdf, aes(y = stitm, x = MonthDate, color = "Item Price",text = paste("R2 value:",round(cor0*100,2),"%"))) + ylab('Price') + xlab('MonthDate')+ggtitle("Plot of Item Price vs Commodity Price")

    print(p)
    })
  })
```

ui.R

```
  shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Commodity Price Vs item Price Plots"),

  sidebarPanel(
  #Selector for file upload
  fileInput('datafile', 'Choose CSV file',
          accept=c('text/csv', 'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain')),

   #These column selectors are dynamically created when the file is loaded
   uiOutput("asitmno"),

   #The action button prevents an action firing before we're ready
   actionButton("getplot", "Get Plot")
    ),

  mainPanel(
  plotOutput("plot")
  )
 ))
```

Comment: You have a mix of `tmpdf()` and `tmpdf` in your code. Parenthesis is needed. Also you can try to not use `reactive`, and just calculate the data frame inside `renderPlot`.

Comment: I have to convert the monthdate in the dataframe that is given by the user and filter it for the given input value. How do i do both inside render plot?   `df$MonthDate<-as.Date(df$MonthDate, "%m/%d/%Y")` and 
`df<-df[input$ASItemNo %in% input$asitmno]`

Comment: Simply move these code inside `renderPlot` and then use `df` directly. Also it seems that you are missing the closing `})` after `getplot`. Also to use an actionbutton, use `observeEvent` instead of `reactive`.